# What are your favorite sources for news about Machine Learning and Data Science?

Tags: machine-learning

Data Science and Machine Learning include a lot of different topics and it´s hard to stay up-to-date about all the news about papers, researches or new tutorials and tools.

What sources do you use to get all the information?

I use mostly Reddit as my first source and the subreddits [Machine Learning](http://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning) and [R](http://www.reddit.com/r/rstats).

But I would also [Datatau](http://www.datatau.com) and of course the great [KDNuggets](http://www.kdnuggets.com).

Comment: off topic - discussion, opinion, and fist-fights will result.

Comment: ['To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”'](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 5):

I like following certain tags on [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com), as well as the [`r` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) StackOverflow.

[arXiv.org](http://www.arxiv.org) is also pretty cool, it has several subsections devoted to stats and ML.

Answer (score 5):

You could also try:

- [Quora](http://www.quora.com)
- [Machine Learning Daily](http://paper.li/MachineCoding/1370791453)